# form action dont work right

Tags: html, forms, action

this is my code:

```
<form  action="<%=Request.QueryString["SubmitTo"] %>/test" method="get" id = "myform">
<input runat="server" id="sendBtn" name="sendBtn" type="submit" value="Finish" />
<input type="hidden" name='Id' value="<%=Request.QueryString["Id"] %>"/>
</form>
```

Lets take

Request.QueryString["SubmitTo"]="google"

Request.QueryString["Id"]="123456"

Instead the form goes to google/test, It goes to

```
http://Localhost:49607/MyWeb/progect/google/test?ctl00%24MainContent%24sendBtn=Finish&Id=123456
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: Exactly. Submit form Using get is not a good practice.

Comment: @Or K. r u ok with my answer? let me know if there is any problem.

Comment: @ambarox OK, I will change it to post. but this is not my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try below Code. 
For the Form we can give two action and URL Type could be vary

- An absolute URL - points to another web site (like
  action="http://www.example.com/example.htm")
- A relative URL - points to a file within a web site (like action="example.htm")

For That You have to give Absolute URL coz you trying to direct it to another domain. 
Simply `<%=Request.QueryString["SubmitTo"] %>` might return some page name or requerst mapping and it is Relative URL.

```
<form  action="http://google.com" method="get" id = "myform">
    <input runat="server" id="sendBtn" name="sendBtn" type="submit" value="Finish" />
    <input type="hidden" name='Id' value="<%=Request.QueryString["Id"] %>"/>
    </form>
```

**Please Note** - Submit Form Using GET method is Not a good practice buddy.